# Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'asp' in VS2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I recently installed VS2012 and working on work projects that I used to work on with VS2010. I never had an issue with VS2010 not recognizing asp prefixed tags but VS2012 is. I tried deleting the `ReflectedSchemas` folder under

> C:\Users[User_name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\

but still not working. Anyone ran into this issue in VS2012?

Comment: Can you share some code and example ? What are this tags, maybe the dll that referred on this tag fails to load.

Comment: Something like: <asp:PlaceHolder ID="test" runat="server"> would not be recognized. This is legit for VS2010

Comment: Even asp.net controls need to include some headers and some dll files. Check that your files are included correct.

Comment: Ya the correct DLLs as well as the tag definitions in web.config are there. This works in VS2010.

Comment: Yes.  I am getting this with VS2012 Update 1 in my SharePoint 2010 project on an Application Page.  I've tried deleting files and it didn't work.  I am lost without Intellisense on this.

Comment: Have you tried simply restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: VS2015 Community vommed this up for me, and deleting contents of version 14.0 ReflectedSchemas folder solved it.  Ref: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikhailarkhipov/2005/04/21/asp-is-an-unrecognized-tag-prefix-or-device-filter-what-is-it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not answering this question before. Though I'm assuming VS2012 service pack or update fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 33):

Closing and reopening the file (.aspx file not solution) from solution explorer worked for me in visual studio 2015. Before trying anything else you can give it a try.

[image]

Comment: All these comments are valid but this one worked for me.  Worked in VS 2017 even though closing and restarting Visual Studio did not.

Comment: Lol.  When the solution really is the thing a non-developer would've just tried before asking

Answer (score 25):

Do you happen to have something like this in your Web.Config:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

In that case, remove the entries for the asp tagPrefix (remove the entire section if no other tagPrefixes are left). This worked for me.

Comment: I did have those in my web.config. I removed them but intellisense is still not recognizing the asp tags. This worked for VS2010 even with those entries in the web.config

Comment: Ok, it worked for me in VS2012 when i removed those tags (altough not in VS2010 anymore, so you need to put them back for that)

Comment: I actually had a reference to asp and telerik controls. I was getting the same error for telerik controls though. I removed the references, tried to compile (get errors) and then re-added the references and it works now. Must be a bug with VS.

Comment: Removing `<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>` has just worked for me.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Worked for me too, If someone has this same issue, try apply this change, **close and open again Visual Studio**.

Answer (score 14):

If you are having this "Unrecognised tag prefix 'asp' in VS2012" problem in a Content Page,

> Check whether the Master page, under which you are adding the content page is missing the `**<body>** or <form>` Tag!

If it is missing this tag  by any chance, then this `<asp>` tag is not recognized.

Comment: Thank you! Obscure problem but this fixed it for me. I had been writing the <body> tag dynamically, in code, eg. `<%= GetBodyTag() %>`, so the tag did not appear as such in the `.master` file's HTML. Changed it to eg. `<body class="<%= GetBodyClasses() %>">` - now VS knows the tag is there and the errors have disappeared. Quite ridiculous that writing a tag in code, instead of in HTML, breaks the whole of VS intellisense.

Comment: Quick test: wrap content in body tag ... my error went away immediately. In my case, the legacy VB.Net code-behind page was inheriting from a class which in turn inherited from System.Web.UI.Page. The parent class emits the html/head/body tags in its OnInit(...) function and it seems Microsoft Visual Studio wasn't detecting it, thus the error.

Comment: The site I am maintaining uses an xml template instead of a masterpage, any idea how to get around this without adding a second body or reworking the template system?

Answer (score 9):

For a project setup using .Net 4.0 following lines work.

```
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
```

Comment: Is there any official Microsoft reference for this?

Answer (score 4):

RuudvanFalier's answer got me thinking about tagPrefixes and so I removed the following in my aspx page and then added it back and the warning went away for me.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Comment: I just upgraded to VS2013 RC and had this problem. I didn't have a Register Assembly on my page, but I removed the <%@ Page..... %> and then added it back in and the problem cleared.

Answer (score 4):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="something" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="something" Inherits="something" %>
<br/><br/>
```

Please give an 'enter' after first line. it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get rid of these errors by changing the .Net version (in project properties) from 4.5 back to 3.5.  I then changed it back to 4.5 and the errors didn't return.

Answer (score 3):

Caused due to carelessness

My Problem Fixed

I removed the structure below,

which might be used by .net to identify elements, when i put it back everything worked fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a good solution for those who have removed this. A case where someone may have done that is if you are using the aspx page as an ajax loaded page/content. Adding back the basic structure allows .net to recognize asp tags again. Interestingly any custom User Controls the page can recognize fine. Thanks @ARUN for pointing this out to me.

Answer (score 3):

Simply closing the solution and re-opening it worked for me (or closing Visual Studio and re-opening it).

Comment: YES ! Me too! That is wierd

Answer (score 3):

just cut the page directive line from the page save it without it. Paste the page directive line back and save again. This worked for me. I am using vs2019..

Answer (score 2):

For me, this error start occurring after an error I got during the publishing process (I've set it to compile the .aspx pages as well). Watch out that double-clicking the error will not load your solution source code but a copy in the `obj` subfolder. i.e. **check that you've got your actual source code open**.

Yes, it's a brain-dead error. Yes, I just spent 10 minutes debugging it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to write master page in your aspx page tag

like:

> MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master"

Comment: This did the trick for me; my Page tag was missing the MasterPageFile attribute, and the asp tags worked fine at runtime, but in Visual Studio they were hit and miss.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

Add this on your top of the ASP page after one line where content page is bind to master page. Hope your problem will be fix. It worked for me.

Current: ASP developer at Flippertech

Answer (score 0):

If this error comes on those page which inherits master page, then one possible cause is !DOCTYPE tag that you probably used somewhere in your  page to declare !DOCTYPE as html. Since asp is a asp.net prefix tag not html therefor this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on a asp.net 4 site. Adding 3.5 compatibility fixed it.

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of the existing solutions worked, but one of them rang a bell. I had added some  tags(to include some JavaScript and CSS files references) within the  at the MasterPage in my VS2017 solution, like this:

`<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="behavior.js"></script>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`

I removed those script tags and the error disappeared. Curious thing although, was that *I had other pages which also inherited from that same MasterPage but the error wasn't present there*. However, the error appeared on this specific page which I created in the solution ***after*** adding the scripts to the MasterPage. My idea was to avoid adding those same scripts on each and every page inheriting from the MasterPage, so I added those scripts back again to the MasterPage, just to check.... and the error didn't show up again.
My theory here is that some internal file in Visual Studio gets corrupted, and if you add some scripting or any content to the Master Page and then delete it, or you just modify the MasterPage in order to save changes, those changes rewrite some internal file at Visual Studio, which is used to parse the ASP and HTML content. In other words, it's like "refreshing" the IDE so it parses your page correctly. It's just a theory, but it worked anyway, so I hope this solution works for other people too.