# ASP tags not recognized in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, reference, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have created a simple ASP.NET project in VS 2012 but it is not recognizing AJAX Control Toolkit controls...I have downloaded and added ACT to my toolbox. I have referenced the DLLs in the build on the project page...the solution doesn't understand what the prefix asp on the dropdown control is...

*Update!*

The issue is not with `"` or `'`.

*Update 2!*

Changed the web.config and refactored the the code behind a little bit but still get asp prefix unrecognized...

**Error**
[image]

**Solution Explorer**

[image]

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes for .NET 4.5 see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajax" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- add folder path here-->
    <add key="ediConfigPath" value="~/"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="cmsDB3ConnectStr" connectionString="xkcd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**aspx page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>xkcdCoder</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Content/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <a id="product" class="navbar-brand">xkcdCoder > TransCodes</a>
            <img id="logo" class="navbar-brand" src="/content/img/xkcd_logo2.png" alt="" />
        </nav>
        <section class="login-sect">
            <asp:dropdownlist id="ddHospitals" runat="server" datatextfield='<%#Eval("Custom")%>' datavaluefield='<%#Eval("Custom")%>' xmlns:asp="#unknown">
            </asp:dropdownlist>
            <div class="give-me-space">
                <div class="give-me-space">TranCode</div>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="give-me-space">
                <div class="give-me-space">TranDescr</div>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="give-me-space">
                <div class="give-me-space">PosTranCode</div>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="give-me-space">
                <div class="give-me-space">NegTranCode</div>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <button type="button" title="Submit" class="action-button">Add Code</button>
        </section>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/xkcdCoder.js"></script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public DataSet GetItems()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cmsDB3ConnectStr"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getFacilitiesAll", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
        }
         catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string err = ex.ToString(); //write error message
    }
    return ds;
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack) 
    {
        return; //This will make sure that only once the below code will be executed.
    } else {
            ddHospitals.DataSource = GetItems();
            ddHospitals.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's correct.. paste your html in this link and you will see why it's nagging http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

Comment: See duplicate. Change `datatextfield="<%#Eval("Custom")%>"` to `datatextfield='<%#Eval("Custom")%>'` and so on.

Comment: the link doesn't support html5 and I don't think it answered my question. I added the type of script as an attribute due to its analysis...

Comment: I changed to single quotes and the problem is still not resolved. datatextfield='<%#Eval("Custom")%>' etc

Comment: Did you do that in all places? What is the error now?

Comment: updated error in image. updated code in issue.

Comment: That's a different issue, see [Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'asp' in VS2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809653/unrecognized-tag-prefix-or-device-filter-asp-in-vs2012). It is caused by the `<pages><controls><add tagPrefix="asp"` tag in your config. Replace it with `ajax` or `act` for "Ajax Control Toolkit" or whatever you like.

Comment: changed the other things as you suggested. still the asp prefix error....