# ASP.NET <asp:> not recognized?

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying to catch a variable from a textbox in ASP.NET (can that be done through regular < input > boxes?). But with every tutorial they're using the < asp :> tag. When I try to use it, Intellisense doesn't recognize it, and when I try to compile the whole textbox dissapears.

I try to add it through the web.config file by adding `<pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </controls>
  </pages>`

but then I get an compile error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section pages.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 34:    Line 35:  Line 36:    Line 37:
>    Line 38:
>
> Source File: c:\users\mitchell\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\WebApp_ProjectManager\WebApp_ProjectManager\views\web.config
>   Line: 36
>
> Any suggestions?

I'm trying to catch variables from these textboxes:

```
Benodigdheden:  <br />< input id="project_benodigdheden" type="text" />
                <br />
                Locatie van benodigdheden: <br /> < input id="project_benodigdheden_locatie" type="text" />
```

Comment: Hey - welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you post some of the code you've tried?

Comment: Are you using webforms or mvc (What is the extension of the file you are working on)? Can you show some code of the html and how you are trying to read the value? How are you "trying to add through web.config" ? Please add these details to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'asp' in VS2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809653/unrecognized-tag-prefix-or-device-filter-asp-in-vs2012)

Comment: I've edited my post.